# Building a better DnD item inventory

Tags: r

I'm working on building a Dungeons and Dragons item inventory in R.

The goal is to allow me to callout item name rather than scrolling through my long CSV file with all the items on it. So I can do things like "Handaxe" and R would return the details like price, whether the item is of limited quantity, etc... But I could also do things like "Handaxe + Longbow" and get the combined price for when players are shopping in-game.

This is what my CSV looks like right now:

[image]

This is how I've been setting up my code in R so far:

[image]

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: This really isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. It's not clear who decides what the "right way" is or exactly what your measurement of "efficiency" is in this case. Are you worried about code speed? Coding effort? Something else? Right now your questions are pretty subjective and those types of questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Have you looked in to importing the excel in to R? If you're new, I'd suggest looking at tidyverse/dplyr tutorials e.g. https://uomresearchit.github.io/r-day-workshop/03-loading-data-into-R/. As you have the data already in excel, I think the most efficient is to load it in to R as a data frame, and get familiar with how filters work

Comment: Aside from this being off-topic (very broad, opinion-soliciting), you really need to include properly formatted text for code/data/errors/etc, not images of text. For many reasons why, please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sounds like a good example for a quick Shiny app, since you could pull it out in the middle of the game with your phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some starter code you can edit, to try reading in the data and playing around with it:

```
library(tidyverse)

# ensure in same location as your directory, for ease
getwd()
dt <- read_csv("d&d data.csv")

# hard coded example (as I don't have the data, replace with csv line above)
dt <- data.frame(
  Category=c("Armor", "Weapons"),
  Name=c("Padded", "Dagger"),
  `Cost (Normal)`=c("5 gp", "2 gp")
)
# rename column (read_csv might have slightly different convention, so replace if so)
dt <- dt %>% dplyr::rename("CostNormal" = "Cost..Normal.")

# remove gp and convert to number from character
dt <- dt %>% dplyr::mutate(CostNormal = as.numeric(stringr::str_replace(CostNormal, "gp", "")))

# example of filtering and then summing the cost
input_names <- c("Dagger")
dt %>% dplyr::filter(Name %in% input_names) %>% 
  summarise(., TotalCost=sum(CostNormal))
```